# String representation of array

Tags: go

In the following code, the portion `fmt.Println(string(a)+"\n")` does not work. Is there a generic way to get string representation of a construct like array in go?

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    //Array of size 10
    fmt.Println("Original array")
    var a [10]int
    fmt.Println(a)
    a[2] = 2

    //worked
    fmt.Printf("%v\n\n", a)

    //not working - anyway to get string representation of a?
    fmt.Println(string(a)+"\n")

}
```

To make it more precise, given an object `obj`, we can get string presentation in python using `str(obj)`, in Java using `obj.toString()`, I would like to find out what is the counterpart in Go.

Comment: Are you looking for a different representation than what `fmt.Printf("%v",a)` provides? Or do you just want what is printed to console with `fmt.Printf` returned as a `string` instead?

Comment: @William what output you expect?

Comment: @PaSTE in `python`, there is you can do a `str(..)`, in `java` you can do a `toString()` to get a string representation, i would like to get the counterpart in go.

Comment: @william007 for a complete explanation for why `string(a)` doesn't work you can read up on [`conversion expressions`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi What you are looking for is `Stringer` Interface in `fmt` package

So any variable passed to `fmt` package before printing is checked for its implementation of `Stringer` interface. If it implements `Stringer` Interface, it will automatically call the String function implicitly.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

// type alias for [10]int
type StringerIntArray [10]int

// String formats the StringerIntArray ([10]int) to a string
func (a StringerIntArray) String() string {
    var s string = "My Array is: "
    for i := 0; i < 9; i++ {
        s += fmt.Sprint(a[i]," ")
    }
    s = s[:len(s)-1]
    s+=" With Length:"+fmt.Sprint(len(a))
    return s
}

func main() {
    // Original
    var a [10]int
    fmt.Println("Original Array")
    fmt.Println(a)

    // Modified
    a[2] = 2
    fmt.Println("Modified Array")
    fmt.Println(a)

    // Expected
    var b StringerIntArray 
    b[2] = 2
    fmt.Println("String Array")
    fmt.Println(b)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/lE5gnHXGGF4

The inbuilt types have a default string format defined; If you need to modify it you have to create a custom type and attach a String Funciton

Also from reading your comment I want to add that fmt package knows how to format different types of data but sometimes you want to make output string; and yes the output from fmt is string you can get the string back if you use Sprint, Sprintf functions

you can read more about it here
https://tour.golang.org/methods/17
https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Stringer

Comment: No one seemed to mention this, but you can simply convert any object to a string, with `fmt.Sprintf("%v",obj)`, or `fmt.Sprint(obj)`  https://play.golang.org/p/Vju-xIoUuVG, the Stringer interface gives you more control, but if one simply wants to print a thing / capture the string, there's really no reason to go to that length

Comment: @DavidBudworth I did mention this here "yes the output from fmt is string you can get the string back if you use Sprint, Sprintf functions"

Comment: @ShubhamSrivastava As you have mentioned it slice in the method name, but it's an array.

Comment: @shmsr I approved your edit but i donot have enough rep to accept it

Answer (score 2):

I hope this is what you wanted. I've commented the code as well so that you can understand.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

// type alias for [10]int
type istr [10]int

// istr implements fmt.Stringer interface
// String formats the integer array to a string array
func (a istr) String() string {
    var s string = "["
    for i := 0; i < 9; i++ {
        s += strconv.Itoa(a[i]) + " "
    }
    s += strconv.Itoa(a[9]) + "]"
    return s
}

func main() {
    // Original
    var a [10]int
    fmt.Println("Original Array")
    fmt.Println(a)

    // Modified
    a[2] = 2
    fmt.Println("Modified Array")
    fmt.Println(a)

    // Expected
    var b istr
    b[2] = 2
    fmt.Println("String Array")
    fmt.Println(b)
}
```

Update:

Adding a generic solution that could be extended even further types. Currently, it can convert slice of rune/int/bool to string.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

func ToString(iv interface{}) string {
    var sb strings.Builder
    switch iv := iv.(type) {
    case []int:
        var length = len(iv)
        if length == 0 {
            return "[]"
        }
        sb.WriteRune('[')
        for i := 0; i < length-1; i++ {
            sb.WriteString(strconv.Itoa(iv[i]))
            sb.WriteRune(' ')
        }
        sb.WriteString(strconv.Itoa(iv[length-1]))
        sb.WriteRune(']')
    case []bool:
        var length = len(iv)
        if length == 0 {
            return "[]"
        }
        sb.WriteRune('[')
        for i := 0; i < length-1; i++ {
            sb.WriteString(strconv.FormatBool(iv[i]))
            sb.WriteRune(' ')
        }
        sb.WriteString(strconv.FormatBool(iv[length-1]))
        sb.WriteRune(']')
    case []rune:
        var length = len(iv)
        if length == 0 {
            return "[]"
        }
        sb.WriteRune('[')
        for i := 0; i < length-1; i++ {
            sb.WriteRune(iv[i])
            sb.WriteRune(' ')
        }
        sb.WriteRune(iv[length-1])
        sb.WriteRune(']')
    }
    return sb.String()
}

func main() {
    // Original
    var a []int = make([]int, 10)
    fmt.Println("Original Slice")
    fmt.Println(a)

    // Modified
    a[2] = 2
    fmt.Println("Modified Slice")
    fmt.Println(a)

    // String
    fmt.Println("String Slice")
    fmt.Println(ToString(a))

    // Boolean
    fmt.Println("Boolean Slice")
    var b []bool = make([]bool, 10)
    b[2] = true
    fmt.Println(ToString(b))

    fmt.Println("Rune Slice")
    var r []rune = make([]rune, 10)
    r[0] = 'a'
    r[1] = 'c'
    fmt.Println(ToString(r))
}
```

Comment: Thanks, so there is no built in way to convert it an object to string, and we need to write a new object attach a String() function to it explicitly?

Comment: Not exactly. I used interface (read about intefaces in Go) for this purpose. It could definitely be written in a more generic way. But I don't think there's any builtin to do that.

Comment: @william007 I added a generic (rune, int, bool) example which can be extended. I hope it helps!

Comment: Nice ToString Function implementation